# What is the prediction model to predict the probability?

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, propensity-scores, probit

In a paper, [Dasgupta, 2019](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/065edab3-074f-3b5c-989f-458a046471ed/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7B28766b2a-d4bc-451a-a040-a4f863b653ee%7D) used Difference-in-Difference approach to see whether anticollusion laws implemented by different countries (staggered implementation) affect firms financial flexibility.

[Dasgupta, 2019, p.2610](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/065edab3-074f-3b5c-989f-458a046471ed/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7B28766b2a-d4bc-451a-a040-a4f863b653ee%7D) used an approach  called "**prediction model**"

> by only using pre-leniency observations and predict the probability
> that the firm will be convicted in the cartel case after the passage
> of a leniency law.

In particular, what they did is

> First, we estimate the propensity of a firm to be convicted in a
> cartel case. We use a prediction model based on time-varying firm
> characteristics (asset size, leverage, and ROA), country
> characteristics (GDP and unemployment), and country fixed effects and
> three-digit SIC fixed effects.

I do not understand how they calculate the "**probability that the firm will be convicted in the cartel case after the passage of a leniency law**" like that by using STATA. The one command I can link to is "[predict](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rpredict.pdf)" but it seems not to work in this case.

**From some suggestions, it seems that a good way is to use probit(or logit) model to predict the possibility as mentioned. But I do not understand how can we assign the value of dependent variable (0 and 1) in Dasgupta's study.**. Another suggestion is propensity matching method but I do not understand how to relate to it.

*Another update:
I asked the author already and he said the model being used is "**Linear Probability Model" (LPM)**. Is there any thought for applying this method in this case. Specifically, how to have the number 0 and 1 for dependent variable in the LPM model.*

Comment: "A prediction model" can be anything from logistic regression to a neural network or a random forest. If that is all they say, we can't say more. Note that not everyone here will have access to the paper - and those that do have access may not want to dig through it. Your best bet, assuming the paper really gives no more information, is likely to contact the corresponding author.

Comment: Thanks @StephanKolassa, I asked the author and updated the question as above.